# jQuery on page load trigger already defined bind change

Tags: jquery, bind, keypress, onchange

My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>TEST</title>
</head>

<body>
    How can I get the code to fire on load, maintaining the change/keypress?<br/>
<select id="textFieldId" name="textFieldId">
    <option value="1">End Date</option>
    <option value="2">End Date Plus 30</option>
    <option value="3">End Date Plus Custom</option>
    <option value="4">Print Date Plus Custom</option>
    <option value="5">Static Expiration Date (New)</option>
</select>
    <pre id="ONE">If user selects 1</pre>
    <pre id="TWO">If user selects 2</pre>
    <pre id="THREE">If user selects 3</pre>
    <pre id="FOUR">If user selects 4</pre>
    <pre id="FIVE">If user selects 5</pre>
</body>
</html>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#textFieldId").val("3").change();
    $("#textFieldId").on("change keyup", function(){
        var selectedVal = $(this).val();
        $("pre").hide();
        if(selectedVal == "1"){
            $("pre#ONE").show();
        }
        else if(selectedVal == "2"){
            $("pre#TWO").show();
        }
        else if(selectedVal == "3"){
            $("pre#THREE").show();
        }
        else if(selectedVal == "4"){
            $("pre#FOUR").show();
        }
        else{
            $("pre#FIVE").show();
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

[JSfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/86MPT/11/)

1. Page has drop down list with change/keyup event bound to it
2. User Selects a value with mouse or arrow up/down key to show/hide a layer on page

My question is if there's a built in function within jQuery that will allow me to not only set the selected value of the list, but also fire the function that its bound to.

I have a workaround, which is to remove the show/hide layer in its own function and fire that on change/keyup and initial load.

Is that the best way?

Comment: Here's the workaround to the above, but is there a shorter, more efficient way? Perhaps not? http://jsfiddle.net/86MPT/14/

Answer (score 0):

You can do switch to call the function that is bound to it

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/86MPT/12/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#textFieldId").val("3").change();
    $("#textFieldId").on("change keyup", myFunction);
});

function myFunction(){
    var selectedVal = $(this).val();
    $("pre").hide();
    $("#id" + selectedVal).show();
    switch(selectedVal){
        case "1":
            //call a function
        break;
        case "2":
            //call a function
        break;           
    }       
    return false;
}
```

HTML - modified the `pre` id a bit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>TEST</title>
</head>

<body>
    How can I get the code to fire on load, maintaining the change/keypress?<br/>
<select id="textFieldId" name="textFieldId">
    <option value="1">End Date</option>
    <option value="2">End Date Plus 30</option>
    <option value="3">End Date Plus Custom</option>
    <option value="4">Print Date Plus Custom</option>
    <option value="5">Static Expiration Date (New)</option>
</select>
    <pre id="id1">If user selects 1</pre>
    <pre id="id2">If user selects 2</pre>
    <pre id="id3">If user selects 3</pre>
    <pre id="id4">If user selects 4</pre>
    <pre id="id5">If user selects 5</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey Bob, thanks for the quick response. Here's the alternate solution I mentioned. My only hesitation that I think there's a "Best Practice" approach... http://jsfiddle.net/86MPT/14/

Comment: does each selected values has it's own function to call?

Comment: As i see it there is no problem in your approach. You may try to follow `DRY principle`. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this one with less code [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hScLa/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // INITIAL LOAD OF SCREEN - PRELOAD DATA
    myFunction("4");

    // SUBSEQUENT ACTIO NFROM USER
    $("#textFieldId").on("change keyup", function(){
       myFunction($(this).val());
        return false;
    });
});

function myFunction(i){
     var selectedVal = i;
        $("pre").hide();
        var temp = '#id'+selectedVal
        $(temp).show();

}
```